Topological field of complex numbers as ultraproduct
I am new to model theory so perhaps this will be a trivial or not well-posed question, but it was an interesting fact to me when I found out that $\mathbb{C} \cong \prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\overline{\mathbb{GF}(p)} \big/ \mathcal{J}$, where $\mathbb{P}$ denote the prime numbers, $\mathbb{C}$ the field of complex numbers, $\mathbb{GF}(p)$ the finite field with $p$ elements and $\overline{\mathbb{GF}(p)}$ its algebraic closure. Moreover $\mathcal{J}$ is a free ultrafilter on primes. The isomorphism above is an algebraic one. But is there a way to obtain $\mathbb{C}$ in similar manner as a topological field?

The major difficulty here is that, as far as I can tell, there isn’t a notion of ultraproducts of topological structures. There is a notion of ultraproducts of metric structures, used in continuous model theory, but then some choices have to be made as to how to formalize a field equipped with a metric in continuous model theory.

Not an answer, but something you're likely to be interested in: Prestel and Ziegler's Model Theoretic Methods in the Theory of Topological Fields. This shows that not only are $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$ elementary equivalent (as algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$), but they're even elementary equivalent if you allow access to certain "local" questions about the topologies! This is surprising since their topological structures are VERY different.

I believe that there are other papers citing this one which further develop this "topological model theory", but I don't know if it's been developed to the point of ultraproducts (or indeed if there's a useful notion of ultraproduct at all).
